# Why is my console.log returning undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

I need to access my local variable and I tried it this way. But no luck so far, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

What I `console.log(sum1)`

It returns `undefined`

```
  var sum1;
  const q = query(collection(db, "users"),where("selected", "==", "Gasto"), where("moneda", "==", "$"));
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q,(querySnapshot) => {
    const dolarCurrency = [];
    const months =[];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
      dolarCurrency.push(doc.data().cantidad);
      months.push(doc.data().fecha)
    })
    const hash = months.map((Day) => ({ Day }));
    const hashDolar = dolarCurrency.map(( Amount ) => ({ Amount }))

    const output = hash.map(({Day},i) => ({Day, ...hashDolar[i]}));

    sum1 = output.reduce((acc, cur)=> {
      const found = acc.find(val => val.Day === cur.Day)
      if(found){
          found.Amount+=Number(cur.Amount)
      }
      else{
          acc.push({...cur, Amount: Number(cur.Amount)})
      }
      return acc
    }, [])
    return sum1
    })

    console.log(sum1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling console.log outside of your `unsubscribe` function, which is where the value for `sum1` gets set. This would be easier to see if your code was formatted a little better (always format your code please). Here is the gist of it:

```
var sum1;
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  // sum1 gets set in here eventually (keyword "eventually")
};
console.log(sum1); // value is undefined until the function above gets invoked
```

You need to make sure that function is called before you try to log the value. Another option is to move the log statement inside the function.

```
var sum1;
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  sum1 = ...;
  console.log(sum1);
};
```

Comment: Any possibility to access that sum1 variable from outside? Since I need to use it in another function/return for react native.

Comment: @RobertGrootjen
Since sum1 is initialize in unsubscribe invoked process, You need to call unsubscribe first then you can access sum1 outside of unsubscribe.
                    
Or simply just console.log(unsubscribe())      /* Make sure you have pass arguments when you call unsubscribe     */              
Since unsubscribe return sum1 in the end of invoked, you can get sum1 when unsubscribe has finished invoked process